# How to hide everything but public folder(s) having multiple laravel projects ? (apache)

Tags: apache, laravel, directory, hide, public

I have multiple laravel projects in my htdocs folder:

**htdocs/laravelProjectA**
and
**htdocs/laravelProjectB**

So that if i want to access a laravel route of lets say **laravelProjectA** the corresponding url will be:
**localhost/laravelProjectA/public/myRoute**

The problem is that all the laravel files and folders are inside the htdocs folder and therefore accessible to the Web, meaning that i can enter, for example:
**localhost/laravelProjectA/.env**
and view all the sensible data.

How can I hide all the files and folders but the **public** folder from each project using Apache? So that **localhost/laravelProjetA/.env**, **localhost/laravelProjectA/.gitignore**, and every request for the other files result in a 404 error, or similar.

I know i can leave only the **public** folder inside the htdocs folder for each project and move the other files and folders somewhere else and then change the public/index.php file, but I want to use apache to hide those files in order to have each project in a single directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Server will stop showing files

Comment: That didn't work, it simply blocked directory browsing.